# Duplicate data issue over clustered environment

Tags: java, microservices, cluster-computing

Assume that have an application with 4 instances in a clustered environment. Now multiple users are adding the employee data. How do you ensure that the employee data won't get duplicated? employeeid is generated in backend.

Comment: Why not generate it on database side?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Optimistic locking

Optimistic Locking is a strategy where you read a record, take note of a version number (other methods to do this involve dates, timestamps or checksums/hashes) and check that the version hasn't changed before you write the record back. When you write the record back you filter the update on the version to make sure it's atomic. (i.e. hasn't been updated between when you check the version and write the record to the disk) and update the version in one hit.